# jQuery mobile - phonegap - iPhone - utility app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

i am trying to make a utility app lookalike using JQM and PG.

Any ideas on how to add the little "i" button on the bottom right of the screen and perform JQM's flip animation to another page?

Comment: You can check here information about jQuery Mobile [page transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, got it myseelf 20 mins after i posted. just a link with an "info" image positioned absolutely outside the standart JQM s who's transition is set to "flip".